# How do I cancel a combine subscription within a sink?

Tags: swift, combine

I have a somewhat complicated architecture for a feature in my app.

Sample code is below. My original expectation was that this would only print once, because I call `cancellableSet.removeAll()`. But this actually ends up being called twice, which creates problems in my application.

How do I get this so it only fires what's in the `sink` after the subscription is stored in the cancellable set.

Note that I have a few restrictions here that I'll mention. My sample code is just simplifying this.

- Can't use a `take` or `drop` operation, as this may get called an undetermined amount of times.

```
import Combine

enum State {
    case loggedOut
    case doingSomething
}

let aState = CurrentValueSubject<State, Never>(.doingSomething)
private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

func logUserOut() {
    cancellableSet.removeAll()
    aState.send(.loggedOut)
}

func doSomethingElse() { }
aState.sink { newState in
    print("numberOfSubscriptions is: \(cancellableSet.count)")
    switch newState {
    case .loggedOut:
        doSomethingElse()
    case .doingSomething:
        logUserOut()
    }
    
}
.store(in: &cancellableSet)
```

Comment: This example may be too simplifying to the extent that it loses its objective. What exactly is going on in your app, what "gets called an undetermined amount of times", and what are you trying to accomplish? Do you get many values of `State` being emitted, and you want to not fire a `.sink` after `.loggedOut`?

Comment: I have a few different handlers that respond to universal links in my application. Many of the processes are async, as the app has to bootstrap certain components along the way. When a universal link is totally completed, I need it to let the manager of the handlers know so it can cancel the subscriptions. In my example, you'll see that `cancellableSet.removeAll()` is rendered useless, as the cancellable isn't stored in `cancellableSet` until after `sink` is called. I need to be able to cancel the subscription from within the sink, but I don't know how. I hope this helps.

Comment: Like the only solution I can think of is to call  async on `cancellableSet.removeAll()` but that obviously is terrible :(

Comment: Everything here happens synchronously - the first value emitted, the call to `logUserOut` (which removes from an empty set), then the sending of another value, then adding the `AnyCancellable` to the `cancellableSet`. Is your intent that even in the case of multiple synchronous values being set, you'd be able to stop it from happening?

Comment: When you have a "complicated problem" - that is even difficult to describe, this usually means, you run into a dead end with no good solution. I think, you should rethink your problem, possibly try a total different approach, start over, begin from scratch. It might be relieving. ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper that’s an over generalization. I could also simply not be aware of all the components of the Combine SDK. I’ve provided 1 sentence question (the title) along with sample code. So it’s either possible or it’s not, or there is a workaround.

Comment: @NewDev correct

Comment: Cancellation is asynchronous. You might use some queue to synchronise your actions with cancellation. But I would not do this, because this looks like a hack. There should be a clean solution ;) But I am afraid, for this, we need much more info. A possible solution would be to use some proper state machine. The state machine synchronously "knows" when you "cancel" something, even if this is not yet effective. When the next input arrives, the state machine's transition depend only on the current sate and the input, not on the actual cancellation process (what ever task that might be).

Comment: Thanks @CouchDeveloper that's helpful - I'll see if I can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the subscription starts delivering values synchronously before the call to `sink` returns, and so before the call to `store` even begins.

One way to solve this is to turn `aState` into a `ConnectablePublisher` before subscribing. A `ConnectablePublisher` doesn't publish until its `connect` method is called. So call `connect` **after** `store` returns.

You can use the `makeConnectable` method on any `Publisher` whose `Failure == Never` to wrap it in a `ConnectablePublisher`.

```swift
let connectable = aState.makeConnectable()
connectable.sink { newState in
    print("numberOfSubscriptions is: \(cancellableSet.count)")
    switch newState {
    case .loggedOut:
        doSomethingElse()
    case .doingSomething:
        logUserOut()
    }
}
.store(in: &cancellableSet)
connectable.connect()
```

Comment: Nice -- I assumed Apple would have something for this exact need.

Answer (score 1):

If the queue this code is being run on is a serial one, then maybe you can move the execution of the code inside the sink to the end of the queue. This way, the program will find the time to store the subscription in the set.

```
aState.sink { newState in
    DispatchQueue.main.async { // or whatever other queue you are running on
        print("numberOfSubscriptions is: \(cancellableSet.count)")
        switch newState {
        case .loggedOut:
            doSomethingElse()
        case .doingSomething:
            logUserOut()
        }
    }
}
.store(in: &cancellableSet)
```

It's a bit dirty tho.

Comment: This does work since the operation is run after the store is done. I’ll wait to see if anyone else has any other answers before accepting this though. Thank you so much!